# A definite integral involving trigonometric functions

Tags: definite-integrals

Evaluate
$$\alpha=\int_{\pi \over 6}^{\pi \over 3}\frac{\sin t+\cos t}{\sqrt{\sin 2t}}dt$$

My attempt:

First I tried to substitute ${π \over 2}-x$, but didn't work .

Then I made square in denominator

$$\alpha=\int_{\pi \over 6}^{\pi \over 3}\frac{\sin t+\cos t}{\sqrt{(\sin t+\cos t)^2-1}}dt$$

I could put $\sin t + \cos t =x$ but above is not differentiation of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $\dfrac{d(\sin x+\cos x)}{dx}=\sin x-\cos x$

set $u=\sin x-\cos x$

$\implies u^2=1-\sin2x\iff\sin2x=1-u^2$

Comment: Oh thanks  , i knew it is very simple . Just needed to take a minus out .